# Compiler error when template argument is specified in the constructor

Tags: c++, c++20

My code:

```
template <class T>
class Test {
    Test<T>() = default;
};
```

gives the error:

> error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token   165 |
> Test() = default;

C++ standard used is 20.g++ 11.2.

What is causing this?

Comment: @who ever who closed this - Yes these two questions refer to same problem, but wordings are different which increases chances of finding it in stackoverflow. For example, before posting this question I searched the issue multiple times, but could none of the results contained the question that you refer to.

Comment: "*wordings are different which increases chances of finding it in stackoverflow*" And having the question be closed as a duplicate means that it is now more likely that a person finds the information they're looking for. This is the whole purpose of dupe-closing a question.

Comment: To add to what Nicol Bolas said, don't take duplicate closures as something negative. You're absolutely right that the wording of the questions are different, and that's a good thing. You've helped future programmers who might use similar terms as you have when they face this issue.

Comment: As long as this question is searchable it is fine. But after it is closed is it searchable? Sorry I thought it is not.